# Reference Issuue

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a simple refernce question:

I have a winform project(project A), this project uses another class library project in my solution(project B) which uses another project in my solution(project C).
Project C uses a reference from Nuget.

When I compile project A I get three things:

```
A.exe
B.dll
C.dll
```

The problem is I don't get the dll from Nuget(which is copied into the bin folder of project C but not A's).

Any suggestions?

Comment: So does A do work with C which requires `Nuget`?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Reference dll file, go to `Properties` and set `CopyLocal` property to `true`.

Comment: That doesn't copy it to the other projects output folders. I.e. this does not work.

Comment: It's already set to true, as it is copied to C'c bin folder but not to A's

Answer (score 0):

go to the Nuget dll refernce properties and make it copy Always
then build and check if it get copy

Comment: That doesn't copy it to the other projects output folders. I.e. this does not work.

Comment: Which property should I set to "Always"